# Term for puns in graphics - "Can"cer be beaten

Tags: word-choice, terminology, literary-techniques

Is there a name for this construction or wordplay?

[image]

It can be both:

- Cancer be beaten
- Cancer can be beaten ("Can" in "Cancer" is emphasized for the purpose)

It can be called a *wordplay* or a *pun* but I thought there might be a specific name for it. In this example, it is a phrase within a phrase because there is a word within a word.

I checked this Wikipedia article but nothing seems to fit:
<sub>*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_forms_of_word_play*</sub>

Comment: Would ***Donuts do** make you fat!* count? Does it have to be the same *sound*, or can it just be repetition of the same *letters?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It seems like a similar wordplay. I'm not sure if there is a term that covers both examples?! Do you know any term for your example?

Comment: Maybe an ***orthographic pun***: http://arnoldzwicky.org/2014/01/27/orthographic-pun/

Comment: @Josh61: Getting close! But it is a double meaning of one word. (*IV* can be a Roman numeral or an abbreviation)

Comment: That is just an example I've found on the net, but it  has to do with orthography so orthographic pun, wordplay etc. are a close definition IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the term ***typographic pun***. It is mentioned as a kind of connotative typograhic treatment in the book *Street-Smart Advertising: How to Win the Battle of the Buzz* (by Margo Berman). The book says that when connotative type works as part of the *concept* (main message), it contributes to the overall idea of the promotional material. It is the combining of the verbal and visual message into one total expression.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the book:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like "rebus". It was a type of visual pun. It used to strictly be with icons but it can be done through text.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus

Answer (score 0):

This might be known as a double entendre, where a phrase is open to two interpretations. The secondary meaning is often of indecent or sexualized meaning, but it does not always have to be.

Comment: No. A double entendre does not rely on selectively extracting bits of orthographic words.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a wordplay?  Or more a graphic thing? Instead of "Can cancer be beaten? or "Cancer can be beaten" we only have "Cancer be beaten" with the syllable can in different colour to make us read this syllable as an extra word. I don't know whether there are special terms for such graphic gags, there are too many possibilities for such graphic gags.