# What is called when a word is intentionally spelled in another way to highlight another word that is similar to a part inside of it?

Tags: literary-device

I guess it will be best explained with an example from the text I am reading.

*Dumas* was spelled as *DumbAss* as a means of satire.

What is this called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Term for puns in graphics - "Can"cer be beaten](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254619/term-for-puns-in-graphics-cancer-be-beaten)

Comment: The hypernym is **sensational spelling**: <<Sensational spelling is the deliberate spelling of a word in an incorrect or non-standard way for special effect.... During the 1960s, bands often included in their names misspelled words and/or homophones that played on double meanings of the names as spoken. Examples: The Beatles, an intentional misspelling of "beetles", the Byrds, and Led Zeppelin, in which "led" was deliberately misspelled to make clear it is pronounced lead (as in the metal) rather than the other pronunciation.>> [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Marketing *gurus* who come up with advertising lines like ***Beanz Meanz Heinz*** are not the doyens of primary-school teachers.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, if some teachers got hold of those guys, they'd be toast.

Comment: @WS2 Have you ever heard of the British Milk Marketing Board poster campaign from the 1950s which read _Drinka Pinta Milka Day_? This was so successful that we still talk about our _Daily Pintas_ 60 years later.

Comment: @BoldBen Absolutely! I remember it well, along with "Murray mint, Murray mint, no time to hurry mint".